# Do I owe them a two week notice?

Tags: resignation, united-states, quitting

Coming out of college (graduated in the winter), I had relocated six months ago to take a position as a software developer doing iOS app development; it's an area I was excited about and had experience in. The day I started, the manager told me I was going to be a web developer instead, threw me on a massive project on my own, and breathed down my neck every three days to let me know that I wasn't doing things "fast enough" and was essentially hinting at replacing me.

I wasn't a web developer, I didn't want to be a web developer, and no where in the interview process had being a web developer been something mentioned. Because I had relocated, I couldn't exactly quit on the spot, nor did I have the income post-college to float during a job search after having spent thousands of dollars in moving costs and initial apartment deposits.

I told myself I'd stick it out for six months, pick up some new skills (I didn't know a line of JS and barely any HTML/CSS), and just take this as a challenge before applying elsewhere. During that time, it's been a pretty toxic environment with the manager throwing me under the bus from time to time. For example, he told the CEO that I had clearly said in the interview process that I was a web developer, despite the fact that the job position and details of said position that I applied for were clearly the duties of a software developer in iOS. I haven't really defended myself because the CEO and manager have been very close friends for about a decade.

When I had completed a pretty noticable milestone for a client, the CEO openly expressed that he was impressed with my work (it's utilizing a cutting edge framework to do some neat stuff). The manager, being present, slapped down the CEO's enthusiasm with, "Meh, another company could have hired a guy who would have done a better job in half the time".

I won't go any further but hopefully this presents an idea of the kind of environment this has been, which has caused me many sleepless nights and my first ever panic attack. I have, and have accepted, an offer from another company that has a great environment and management that has been nothing but professional and courteous. They'd like me to start ASAP.

Do I owe it to the company I'm with now to still give them a two-week notice? I'm the sole front-end developer... which means that since I've been here, I've had no one to go to for assistance or guidance in web development, jQuery, etc. This also means that the company would be royally screwed for a bit if I up and left with no notice. But the other company wants me to start immediately and, to be honest, I want to get the hell out of where I'm currently at. I feel like I owe them nothing for the way they've treated me but a part of me feels guilty regardless.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43181/discussion-on-question-by-abitcurious-do-i-owe-them-a-two-week-notice).

Comment: Is two weeks notice your contractual requirement?

Comment: _"I haven't really defended myself because the CEO and manager have been very close friends for about a decade."_ That was your mistake. You have no recourse now.

Comment: You should offer two weeks notice, but given your description of your current employer you shouldn't be shocked if they walk you to the door and toss you to the curb. It would be a good idea to remove all personal belongings from your office space before turning in your notice just in case something like this happens.

Comment: +1 to @BobJarvis comment -- I had an employer who did this to me once, I had to call someone and have them go get my stuff for me. The manager didn't even want to let them do that, but I warned him that those are my personal possessions and that I would be more than happy to get the police involved on charges of theft if he would not let me reclaim them.

Comment: You don't owe anything to them but you do owe it to yourself to provide and serve out a two-week notice. If you choose to not give a two-week notice then you are essentially planning to remove this company from any professional conversation about what you did there and how it helped you to grow into the amazing developer that you are 5 years from now :-). "Straight out of college I was hired at a very fast-paced company named Barnacle Brothers where I took on a web developer role and received praise from the CEO directly, blah blah blah."

Comment: Side note, if the company you're jumping to considers "ASAP" to mean without notice, that's a red flag about *that* company: it means they are willing to hire people who don't give any notice when they leave, so you'll be working with people who might do the same at any time!!

Comment: Funny.. do you get a 2 weeks noticed when being fired? Why do people care so much when from your question you were treated like shit.

Comment: «the company would be royally screwed for a bit if I up and left with no notice» Who cares?

Comment: A two-week notice is not required. They don't _deserve_ a 2-week notice. But you will never regret taking the high road. So find a new gig, start in 3 weeks, give the 2-weeks notice, and enjoy the extra week of time to dump your emotional baggage.

Comment: @Insane I think most people do get 2 weeks notice when they are fired.  However there is a concept called constructive dismissal that may be applicable here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_dismissal).  "when an employee resigns as a result of the employer creating a hostile work environment. Since the resignation was not truly voluntary, it is in effect a termination."

Comment: @emory People get 2 weeks when they're being laid off, I think. Correct me if i'm wrong but I don't think people get 2 weeks when they're being terminated aka fired

Comment: @Insane under employment at will, there is no mandatory notice period either way.  Most reputable employers give 2 weeks notice.  OP should give 2 weeks notice, unless he feels that he has a "hostile work environment" in which case he is being "constructively dismissed" and is not quitting without notice but just acknowledging his "de facto" firing.

Comment: @emory I don't care about if it's mandatory. That's besides the point

Comment: @Insane in my experience and in my opinion, most employers give two weeks notice to fired employees.  But there are certainly some that don't and I have not actually conducted a thorough review.

Comment: @corsiKa: I completely disagree. "ASAP" means "please give your notice this week, work through it as obligated, then come and work with us".

Comment: I would say make sure you have some of your coworkers' contact information before you give the notice. You'll likely lose all company email access and such if they decide to kick you out, and you might want to keep in touch with them after an event like this.

Comment: @emory I suppose cultural norms differ, but where I live fired people tend not to be given advance notice, but are given a severance pay equal to what their pay would have been for some time period (a couple of months, for example.)

Comment: "*but a part of me feels guilty regardless*" - this is normal for your first job.  It's something you need to get over.  If you were in criticial position, they would have changed your contract to require a much longer notice period (eg 6 months isn't uncommon for critical positions).

Comment: Does your contract say 2 weeks notice? Do you have any unspent leave?

Comment: @Insane Yes. Everybody get the notice, as defined in contract. Often you get the notice and are asked to leave the building, but on the paper you're still employed and get money for the remaining period. Option 2: both sides agree to terminate the contract immediately. And third option: one side accuses the other of already breaching the contract. Eg when employee is not doing his job at all or employer is not paying for the job done. But that's a serious accusation that has to be proven. Bottom line: job is just a contract, both sides are equally bound by it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit 100% that's what I hope that company means as well. My comment was saying "If the company thinks ASAP means walk out today and start with us tomorrow then you're gonna have a bad time." On the other hand, if they mean "Put in your notice tomorrow and work for us when that period is up" you're going to have a much better time.

Comment: @Kik: You do when you are contractually obliged to work out a notice period. Although that would be here; in the US I hear things are not as well-regulated.

Comment: @corsiKa: Yeah.

Comment: @reirab what is the difference? did you really expect you would get moved to a corner office on the top floor and the keys to the executive restroom during your final 2 weeks?

Comment: @emory What? I'm not sure I understand the bit about the corner office. The difference is that the fired employee isn't given time to potentially sabotage the company as 'revenge' for being fired. Someone with network administrator access could wreak some real havoc, for example, especially if they also have access to the backups. They could delete important stuff, install a trojan, grab proprietary data to take with them, etc. An engineer could screw up the code base or introduce subtle design flaws or delete/corrupt/steal design information, etc.

Comment: @abitcurious : so what did you decide and how did it work out?

Comment: This sounds like my old job. Sole web developer with no experience. I accomplished lots, but eventually quit for similar reasons (though that's not what I told them). I gave two weeks notice, but after a week they said, "you can go home, we'll pay you the second week on your final pay-check".

Comment: @corsiKa ASAP != now

Comment: @Noldor130884 Naturally. If you accept the offer at 3pm, no one is expecting you to be there at 5pm. Some feel you should be there the next morning though. As I said, how the employer defines ASAP could be a red flag.

Answer (score 176):

**Serve the two weeks notice.**

Your new employer will likely respect this decision, as they will want the same courtesy someday.*

For your former company, leaving without notice gives the perception that you are unprofessional.  You likely don't care about the former company's perception (sounds like it's not great already), but you SHOULD care about how your former *coworkers* perceive you.  You never know when you'll run into one of them at another company, and you want a favorable first impression at every new job.  Would you rather be remembered as the developer who was treated poorly and resigned gracefully? Or the former coworker who left in a huff?

As pointed out by Michael Kohne's comment below, some companies will decide to walk you to the door immediately, even if you give two weeks notice. If your employer happens to fall under this category. You may be able to tell your future employer you are available earlier than expected. Also, this is a good reason to sneakily remove any valuables from your desk before giving notice. You don't want to have difficulties getting your stuff.

*If you already told your new employer you could start immediately, you may be best served by leaving your old employer without notice.  You will burn bridges with your former coworkers, but you also don't want to start your new job on the wrong foot.  First and last impressions are both important.  If this is the case, favor the new employer's first impressions and try to avoid cases like this in the future.

Comment: +1 Well said, the notice serves the employee more than the employer.  Two weeks is professional, but it will still "punish" the old employer because they won't be able to replace you that quickly.

Comment: Also, some companies (foolish ones in my mind) will decide to have you leave immediately. Give notice and see what happens. Oh - and take as many of your personal belongings out of the building as you can BEFORE giving notice. You never know how they'll react and it's possible (though VERY unlikely) that you'll have trouble getting your stuff.

Comment: `you SHOULD care about how your former coworkers perceive you` if they know his situation they won't blame him.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43257/discussion-on-answer-by-djohnson10-do-i-owe-them-a-two-week-notice).

Comment: Leaving without serving the notice period is risky, even if you promised the new employer.

Comment: Agreed, but breaking a promise to a new employer probably more so. Hence the advice to avoid that situation in the future.

Comment: I left a job with only 1 weeks notice, and I was the last developer too.  They lived, even gave me some freelance work.  Wish them good luck and move on.  If they decided they didn't need you anymore, they would walk you out the door.

Comment: @MichaelKohne 's contribution should be added to the answer, IMO. I've seen someone not even allowed to go get their purse, and it took over three hours for someone to go get it. The lady was just sitting in the parking lot with no car keys to go home or even cell phone to call a cab. Luckily at lunch a (now former) coworker saw her, ran back to her desk to get her phone and keys, and she waited for the rest to come in the mail. Don't let it happen to you!

Comment: @MichaelKohne, added your comment to the answer.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: @Jim Yes.  But do they know the situation?  And the day after he's gone when there are questions about why he left so abruptly, will there be people there to tell his side of the story?  If they knew his situation, they might also be giving their notice.

Answer (score 152):

This is a very subjective area.  You already have another job, so this company's ability to "get back" at you is pretty low.

However, the CEO publicly commended you, so I'm believing that this is not a company problem, but a manager problem.

Here's a draft that you may want to use to get started:

> Dear Mr. CEO
>
> Thank you for your recognition of my work for Big Pants Industries.  I appreciated your taking the time to notice my work.
>
> As you are aware, I am an iOS developer, and while I was hired to do iOS development, I was assigned this web development project instead.  I have enjoyed the work, but it is not what I was hired to do, and is not the path I am trying to take in my career.
>
> I have taken a position with another firm in order to pursue this goal, and will be leaving ThisCo, LLC on M/D/YYYY.
>
> I really do want to thank you for the individual recognition you showed for my work.  It means a great deal to me.
>
> Thank you,
>
> iOS Guy

By turning in your notice to the CEO, rather than the hostile manager, you are sending every message that you need to about your working environment, and you're not burning any bridges.

However, this is entirely your call.  Taking the high road, though, will feel much better 5 years from now than rage-quitting will.

Comment: I see your point, but how will the CEO reconcile the Manage saying the OP was a web guy vs the OP saying he is an iOS guy?  My guess is the CEO will side with the manager especially if the CEO had nothing to do with the initial hiring, which would invalidate the underlying ideas you are trying to present.

Comment: @PeterM - You can't fight that one.  You don't want to be in a he said / I said argument, especially when it means nothing to the CEO at that point.  They lost the employee.  What he should have been assigned is no longer important.  This is the "polite" equivalent of the mic drop.  "I'm iOS.  Curious out! [mic drop]"  You've said what happened, and there's no more discussion.  Whether they believe it or not is irrelevant, now.

Comment: I suppose my point is if you have an expectation that they won't believe it then why write it that way?  Because if CEO doesn't believe it then it potentially engenders a negative reaction (and hence potential bridge burning) - which is something that the OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: @PeterM - I understand what you're saying.  *My* point is that the employee is the only one who knows the reason he changed jobs.  If they can't accept what an employee says when told why the employee is leaving, no amount of argument is going to make a difference.  Make your case.  Make it politely.  Thank them for the opportunity, and walk out with your dignity intact.  You can only control you.  You can't control them.  You can only be honest.  The rest is not up to you.

Comment: It sounds like this is a small company, but the CEO probably does not handle turnover.  It's probably not helpful to give your notice to him and probably doesn't follow whatever policies they might have.  I think the sentiment here is good, however, and it might be worth sending him a similar thank-you note on the final day.

Comment: I think that email would be a good way to offer a counterpoint to the manager's BS before heading out. I like it.

Comment: I agree sending it to the CEO is a great choice. It lets him know why your leaving but without "name calling". The OP states that he's an iOS developer and the job isn't a good fit.

Comment: I really, really like this draft. Assuming that the CEO is no dummy this keeps your reputation absolutely clean while putting the manager into a very, very awkward position.

Comment: One little quibble.  *Never* say "As you are aware", or "As you know".  The CEO may actually not be aware of that, and it can ruffle feathers you don't need to ruffle.  Say "I'm an iOS developer, not a web developer, and, while I interviewed for and was hired to do iOS development, I was assigned to this web development project instead."

Comment: @JohnR.Strohm - That's the bit that makes this whole approach accomplish its goals.

Comment: I disagree with this draft. The resignation letter should state that you are resigning effective such-and-such date, and that's it; no more than two or three sentences. If they want to know why you're leaving, they'll ask you during your exit interview. Putting it down in writing won't help anything, and some people might see it as defensive.

Comment: I agree with that draft. The CEO might think you are lying and the manager is right. But he will for sure remember that letter. And if in the future, something similar happens, he will still remember it. While for you it doesn't make any difference, for the next guy that get hired it could change the world if the CEO remembers that this other guy that quit also said he wasn't hired as web developer.

Comment: This email draft is _excellent_. The subtle approach is very powerful.

Comment: @JohnR.Strohm true, never assume the CEO knows the "details" about what goes on outside his tower. A better wording might be "You may be aware that...", or "I do not know if you are aware or not..." or similar. Also, the part where he says "it is not the work I was hired to do" is false - it is the work he was hired to do, they just lied about what that work was to get him.

Comment: @WesleyLong, I don't disagree with the thrust.  I disagree with the "As you know".  The CEO may not know.  Assuming he does, and telling him he already knows this, is patronizing.  It ruffles feathers you don't want or need to ruffle.

Comment: While I understand that this question and answer may be a bit dated already, I thought I'd weigh in on the "As you know..." construction being discussed. I agree in principle with the answer author that this is a crucial bit of the conversation, but also with, e.g., @john-r-strohm that there's risk in it. My preferred wording (which puts more of the onus on the author/OP) is: "It was my understanding when I was hired that my position required an iOS developer. While I have enjoyed the web development work assigned me, it is not the path I am trying to take in my career."

Comment: @DerrellDurrett, I completely disagree.  The "as you are aware" effectively plays dumb to any possibility that the CEO may *not* be aware of that fact.  He *should* be aware of it—and the letter is not merely civil but is actually extremely friendly and entirely uncritical.  Putting in an "it was my understanding" paints the whole scene in entirely different and far more negative light and *is accusative* because it implies the employer didn't describe the job properly.  The draft given is fantastic.

Comment: Take two letters, one with two weeks notice, and one for immediate resignation, including some phrase like "As you have agreed to an earlier resignation, I am resigning effective ( and have a space for the date)" - mark them so you don't get confused, then go and talk to the CEO and say you appreciated his feedback on the web design, but you want to work in IOs dev as the position was advertised as. And then simply ask if he wants two weeks notice or if you can be released immediately. Depending on his answer hand him the appropriate letter.

Answer (score 40):

Golden rule is to never burn bridges, no matter how badly you were treated. The sad fact about this world is that a workplace has more control over you than you do of them. Reputation means everything but never forget how you were treated.

With that said, I know you're upset but try to be the bigger person here. Put in your two weeks, say goodbye, leave your contact information, and then leave heading on to bigger things. You're going to be a professional and I highly recommend being one even in the worst situations.

It's a small world, and it would be a shame if you met anyone there again. And trust me there are plenty of cases of that being true, even when moving or in large tech areas.

Comment: There is a time and a place to burn bridges (EG being physically threatened), but I don't see this as the case here.

Comment: @PeterM I think your right about a time and place to burn bridges, but I disagree that this isn't the case. Imagine being a fresh college grad, relocated for a job that you told you'd be doing iOS dev work for, and then being told on day one, "Hey, you're a web dev now and there's no one here to train you". The op said the manager gets on him every few days with threats of termination. That's pretty messed up shit, threatening to fire a new kid who's trying to learn/do a job in tech that s/he didn't sign up for and you're not willing to help him/her.

Comment: @PeterM And then when the OP hits a milestone, the manager disrespects her/his work to the CEO? Nah, no thanks, I'd be out of there immediately and never look back.

Comment: @8protons The OP has been sucking it up for 6 months already, so another 2 weeks is nothing in comparison.  The time and the place to quit on the spot is when it hits the fan, not some time down the track when its all water under the bridge.  IMHO doing a mike drop now is the wrong thing and would seem childish to do so now.

Comment: @PeterM I feel you but sometimes after you've suffered for 6 months, each day is progressively worse than the one before. The OP said he/she had a panic attack; that kind of stress is nothing to shrug off.

Comment: @8protons Leaving at the earliest opportunity (after serving your notice period) is the way to go, however, there's no reason to be insulting or snarky on the way out. I've lost count of the previous colleagues I've run into at tech expos, conferences, etc... It's always better to be able to nod and smile rather than feel you have to dodge away. What does a mic drop now gain you beyond a fleeting moment of smug satisfaction?

Comment: @Basic when did I ever suggest a "mic drop"? I suggested that the OP get on with their life ASAP if that's what they want to do. Leaving that toxic job immediately and starting the next one isn't a mic drop. Saying crap on the way out the door is- which I never suggested.

Comment: Although the urge to burn bridges is strong, this is good advice. Because in 5 years that arse of a manager might be gone, the CEO might be hiring, and you might be a star programmer working there again. I've burned bridges in the past and then found out years later those places were desperately hiring at crazy amounts of money. Enough that I would have gone back there despite how terrible it was before just for the cash.

Comment: Burn baby burn.  I don't think it will make a difference in this case.  The manager is going to be mad as hell and blame you for everything for years to come wether you leave tomorrow or 2 weeks.

Comment: Someone else wrote: "Never burn a bridge. If you have to, blow it up to smithereens, never to be rebuilt. But don't burn a bridge".

Answer (score 38):

I'm going to argue the unpopular point:

> ***Follow your own interests.***

If they were getting rid of you, you'd have to clean out your desk on the spot, with someone standing over you.

Yes, generally it's good form to give notice. However:

- this is your first job after college
- you've only been there for 6 months
- you already have another job secured

What this means is that you no longer depend on these people for a reference. In fact, in just a year or two you won't even need to include that experience in your resume if you so wish, and no one will expect references from that long ago anyway.

My opinion is to do whatever you feel is appropriate. Stop stressing yourself out, tell them you quit, take a few days to relax, and then start your new job with a fresh smile on your face.

Comment: Decency aside, there is a better chance than you think of a future employer knowing someone you worked with at this company, and having them say "abitcurious? Yeah, he was the guy who quit without notice."

Comment: @PeterM What about the tag "united-states" doesn't tell you what country the OP is in? :P

Comment: @8protons  D'oh .. obviously I shouldn't be allowed on here without supervision

Comment: Re: "If they were getting rid of you, you'd have to clean out your desk on the spot, with someone standing over you": Many companies give severance when they lay people off. The details of this severance vary wildly (and some companies don't do it at all), but it's pretty common for it to be at least two weeks' salary, and is essentially the company's equivalent of giving two weeks' notice.

Comment: This entirely depends on what the contract says.  If the contract says he needs to give two weeks notice, he really should work the two weeks.  He might not depend on that company for a reference now, but when he leaves the next company, his third hirers will almost certainly check back.  If the contract says "no notice period on either side until 12 months in" though, he can legitimately say goodbye any time he likes.

Comment: I feel like this is the only answer here that is grounded in reality. I understand the _"uber professional with honor"_ route of giving a two weeks notice despite being treated like a POS- yeah, burning bridges can rarely help. But if the OP already landed a job, who stated they want her/him as soon as possible, it would seem in the OP's best interest to get the hell out of there and move on with their life. It may suck for other employees but that's not the OP's problem if everyone is well aware that management is scum.

Comment: @8protons - oh good, I'm not crazy, lol. I was starting to think I'm some kind of monster for thinking I'd just leave.

Comment: @AndreiROM Seeing this answer as the only one of its kind made _me_ think that _we're_ monsters for holding this perspective haha. I Googled some queries like "quitting w/out notice" and most professional blogs/articles say that it's completely acceptable if you're in a toxic environment. I admire that The Workplace has so many "do the professional thing" kind of answers but at the same time it's easier said than done to be a miserable employee to keep eating s!#@ for another two weeks. "take a few days to relax, and then start your new job with a fresh smile on your face." is key here.

Comment: @ruakh: If you quit on the spot, and save them 2 weeks pay on you, can you also look at that as giving your two weeks? I mean, if money == time,  from their firing you perspective, why not? I love this answer. Get out.

Comment: @fractalspawn: I'm sorry, but your comment does not make sense. The *direct* equivalent of the company's paying severance would be for the employee to offer to continue working for free for a while. No one does that. Instead: decent employees give notice, so the company has some time to prepare; decent companies give severance, so the employee has some financial buffer.

Comment: @ruakh - you mention decent employees, and decent companies, but I see no reason to be a decent employee to a company that treats me like crap.

Comment: @ruakh, yes, maybe the "direct" equivalent, but what about the "opposite" equivalent? If you fire me and give me 2 weeks salary as "my leave notice", or I quit and *save* (i.e. give) you 2 weeks pay as "my leave notice. I see those things as the same concept: 2 wks money === 2 wks time. Also, I side with AndreiROM, this company sounds like a lemon. When life gives you lemons... say f**k the lemons and bail :)

Comment: This is the best answer. The notice period is a courtesy that should normally be given and sometimes even lengthened. HOWEVER if you you're ready to go, and staying won't actually help your career or wellbeing, make some minimal preparations and give a week or shorter notice... Just say you've prepared ahead of time and there's nothing else to do. Definitely take a MINIMUM of a week off between jobs to decompress and recharge.

Comment: @Graham: "If the contract says no notice period ... he can legitimately say goodbye any time". Note that by saying this you are in *strong disagreement* with a lot of people saying that the professional thing is to work notice, without reference to any contract. I don't really disagree with you myself, and to me if a company doesn't have the guts to give notice periods then it shouldn't receive them. But there is a genuine issue of culture that goes beyond contracts. For that matter, at-will employees often don't have a contract, but can still be held to unwritten standards in references.

Comment: @SteveJessop Fair point.  My main issue was disagreeing with Andrei, that it doesn't matter if you quit without working your contractual notice period.  If the contract specifies a notice period, it *will* affect future job prospects very badly if you don't work it.  If there's nothing in the contract, it *may* be an issue in future but at least you're in a position you can defend.

Comment: This is the most realistic answer. You're not burning bridges, you're burning a dirt road with thumbtacks at every step. Show that manager what happens when you knowingly fool a smart, honest, hard-working person. The "honorable" and "professional" approach does not apply in a case like yours.

Comment: @Graham I agree with you. If OP is bound to give notice, not doing so is a breach of contract and a liability.

Comment: @fractalspawn The problem is, a employee paid $X is generally worth $X+Y.  At any level.  That's how company's make a profit.  Their costs are less than their revenue.  So if you quit, sure, they no longer have to pay you the $X, but if they do not have someone to replace you, they may also be out the $Y.  This is generally the point of a notice period.  It affords the company the the time to find a replacement so they do not miss out on the $Y.  When they lay you off but still pay you the $X, they have afforded you the opportunity to find a replacement job without losing the $X.

Answer (score 10):

A company is required to look after its own interests. You are the only one who will look after yours.

But what is in your best interests. I have always taken the high road, always given notice, and always made myself available to questions from my replacement. Why? **Because long-term it was in my own best interest.**

I have seen cases where I left company A to work for Company B and within a couple of years we acquired company A. Now I either work for people from my former company, or they work for me, etc.

And people you worked for could leave that company and join your new company. Or you could be consulting one day and run across these people.

You will never know. But one thing is certain: it's a very small world.

I have run across this situation before, where the new company wants me in there without delay. If it's just a preference, then I kept to my two week notice. But I have had a situation where I was needed for a strategic play right away. In that case, I worked it out with my former employer that I kept to my two week notice, but with a few of those days working for the new employer.

Usually, once the new employer has made the decision of whom to hire, they won't be put off if you ask them to wait the normal two weeks. In fact, it will probably just show you to be an ethical player. However, it might be wise to call them, state that you think it's the right thing to do, and ask if that is something they can support.

Here's another thought. Generally poor managers are known by their uppers to be so. But if they get things done, it's somewhat overlooked. And there are often timing issues with replacing them even if they wanted to. I can be somewhat friends with one of my managers, but that doesn't mean I'm blind. It wouldn't surprise me if this CEO knows what a poor manager this guy is. But I'm not sure you even need to point it out. When you leave, the CEO will probably guess correctly. But don't be surprised if he comes to you and asks. So be prepared with what you will or will not say.

I feel for you. I know how awful it is to stick it out when you want to bolt out of there.

Answer (score 9):

You have to make your own decision here, but it seems there isn't really a bridge to burn.  I would accept the new opportunity.  Tell your manager that you are leaving and good luck.

Don't bad mouth him, but be frank. I have found a better opportunity and am moving on immediately.

If you feel compelled, you could write a letter to the CEO and indicate that you are sorry to leave on such short notice, but you immediate manager made things toxic for you and a new opportunity has arisen where timing does not permit finishing out a notice period.  Give him a few details like that you were hired to develop iOS, had no experience in Web and never indicated during the hiring process you did.  You are sorry your manager misled him in this area, but you wanted to clear the air as you left.

Comment: Bear in mind if you are in the US, slandering you publicly or to another company is illegal and you would have good grounds to sue them should they do so.  Don't threaten this or anything, but rest assured that if they 'come after you' they will pay for it.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a contract consult it for any mention of notice period.  Norms in the US would be that you wouldn't have an employment contract and that your employment would be "At will" (although this can vary some state to state).  If you are employed at will and there is no specification of notice period in any contract you've signed with them you are legally free to quit on zero notice.

It's not a good idea and it isn't how a professional behaves but if that's how you want to go, nothing is stopping you.  Good luck.

Comment: It also may be worth consulting the contract to see if it explicitly mentions your job role and job description.  Not that I'm up with legalities of employment law, but I would wonder if getting you to do a different job to the one stated in the contract is a contract violation on their behalf.

Answer (score 4):

This question has been asked before.

I am in the no-notice camp. If the company had laid you off or fired you, you would get 0 days notice. You owe them nothing.

That being said, do not be rude about it. Just be straightforward: "I am taking a new job with a different company starting tomorrow (or the day after tomorrow or whenever), is there anything you would like me to finish up before I go? Make sure you have your personal belongings already removed because small employers sometimes go bananas when somebody quits on them, so you don't want to lose stuff in the course of the exit.

Employment at will is just that: employment at WILL. You can leave whenever you want and you have every right, both legally and morally to do so. If they wanted to engage you permanently, then they should have agreed to a CONTRACT with fixed dates, which they did not do which means they consider you disposable. It works both ways.

Comment: This sort of thing comes back. Later on, other ex-employees will say, 'Oh I remember him. He's the one that quit without notice.' and the OP loses the job competition on tie-breaks.

Comment: @TonyEnnis I have seen numerous employees working either for me, or for companies I work at quit without notice. One guy I remember quit to go work for JP Morgan and another to Google and a couple others to Twitter. I can tell you: I seriously doubt that JP Morgan, Google or Twitter either know or could care less that they quit their former job without notice.

Comment: If you quit w/o notice for ethical reasons, this is perfectly fine.
That is, if the company is forcing you to do something unethical or illegal (like load pirated software, fudge data, etc), then quit w/o notice - be sure to let them know if you get anything but a shiny review, you'll press charges (or sue). Make sure to have all the evidence before making your announcement. Don't worry about future employers, most companies won't give a reference at all (just acknowledgement) for fear of legal repercussion.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to offer a longer term view on why you should put in your two weeks notice: employment background checks.  As you advance in your career as a dev and land jobs with more thorough background checks, they will call your former employers and ask things such as:

```
Job start and end dates
Titles held
Salary
Job duties
The reason for termination (in some states) and rehire eligibility
```

As per http://www.hireright.com/blog/2015/03/employment-verification-a-crucial-check/

That way you do not have a situation where your previous employer reports you walking out on them without notice.

Now, there is a silver lining, put in your two weeks note, do the bare minimum, or slightly less, don't put in any effort to transfer your knowledge and politely tell your current employer contacting you is off limits post-employment, but remember that your co-workers will be collateral in this exchange, which is something to consider against it.

I would also follow Wesley's advice on resigning to the CEO instead of the manager & possibly putting something in there to warrant a discussion about your manager, such as questionable leadership and a lack of technical knowledge.

Lastly, consider references, if you want a reference from one of the folks mentioned above, it may be best to quietly put in your two weeks, and leave without doing anything extra.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to notice:  Your direct manager has already been outspoken about his disdain for you and your work.  Do not expect that your leaving will change his tune suddenly, if someone calls for a reference.

Also, most every employment verification process consists of basic "name, rank, serial number" data:  Dates of employment, job title, manner of separation.  Most companies now have strict policies against giving out much more than this, as it opens them up to slander/libel lawsuits (whether justified or not).

So, do not worry about the reference.

The "what's good for the goose is good for the gander" principle does come into play, in that if you're willing to dump employer A on no notice, you're also likely to dump employer B in the same way.

Answer (score -2):

I know the OP has since moved on to green pastures, but I want to add another perspective for "two weeks" notice.

If you leave immediately, you will miss an important part of leaving a job: closure. If it is possible close this chapter of your life on good terms, and prepare yourself emotionally for the next, new and exciting chapter, do so.

After you give notice about leaving a job, the last two weeks can be the best time of employment. You are not assigned new work, friendly co-workers will take you out to lunch and drinks, there is no need for overtime, and deadlines become meaningless. Any stress your boss may have given you disappears, as this manager ceases to have any power over you. (I gave 3 weeks notice once to extend this pleasant time)

The most important part of any job are the people you meet. Say goodbye to your coworkers, and share the horror stories of the evil manager together. During these two weeks, as the facades fall away, you will know which relationships will continue into the distant future, and which will be simple LinkedIn connections.

You may find that other peers at the same level as you, with whom you had conflict, will become very warm. For others, this is the chance to resolve any interpersonal conflicts and depart on good terms.

It is unfortunate that your first boss was an abusive, lying piece of &^%#&^#. If you are not careful, the toxins from this broken relationship can poison your future relationships with managers, and even subvert your career. For this reason, it is important to speak your mind when your boss asks you what your plans are. You should tell him frankly, and tell the CEO also, that they deceived you, they clearly broke a promise about what your work assignment would be. Tell them that their lies put you, a new professional, in financial hardship for no useful reason, when they could have simply hired somebody to do web development. Try say it without anger or malice, and make it clear that they did something wrong to you personally, and that they should refrain from behaving this way with other people, especially new professionals, in the future. The reason to tell them this is to let this angst out of your system; you do not want to carry this into your future relationships with new managers and coworkers. This is a difficult tasks, with a ton of emotional strain, but if you can do it, it will be liberating.

Comment: Is this normal? 3 down votes and not a comment? It obviously isn't spam, and not a trolling. I address the question honestly, with a slight frame shift. The question poses "Do I owe them?" but I think it would be better asked "Should I..."

Comment: Even more, my first job out of uni had a very similar situation. After 20 years perspective, I think what I write here is more than relevant. It is easy to let a horrible experience poison perspective.